# Pattern of grey color

Tags: php, excel

```
<?php
require_once 'Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php';

$workbook = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();

$format6 =& $workbook->addFormat();
$format6->setBgColor('green');
$format6->setPattern(6);
$worksheet->write(1, 1, 'the bg', $format6);

$workbook->send('setBgColor.xls');
$workbook->close();
?>
```

Can you please tell me the the pattern for "Grey" color.as it is 6 in case of green .

Answer (score 0):

It may be hard to answer without knowing what 'Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php' contains.

Have you tried simply changing `$format6->setBgColor('green');` to `$format6->setBgColor('grey');` (or 'gray', the spelling is interchangeable)

Answer (score 0):

15, 16, and 48 are all grays.  See this page for a full list: http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/colors.htm

Pass these values to `setBgColor`.  `setPattern` changes between solid fill, dots, etc.